# TFS and Local Build Differences

Tags: tfs

In our solution we have a ".nuget" folder. This folder does NOT contain NuGet.exe. Instead, we always ensure the latest NuGet.exe is downloaded at build time using this property in NuGet.targets:

```
<DownloadNuGetExe Condition=" '$(DownloadNuGetExe)' == '' ">true</DownloadNuGetExe>
```

This works great on a developer's machine. The latest version of NuGet.exe is always downloaded.

Unfortunately, there is a problem on the TFS Build Server -- for security reasons (and out of my control), it does not have access to the Internet and so it cannot download NuGet.exe as needed. Instead, it has a local copy (local to the server) of NuGet.exe that we must use.

The question then is, How can I tell the Visual Studio Build System to always retrieve NuGet.exe from the Internet and tell the TFS Build system to use the local copy of NuGet.exe? I'm sure it has something to do with build variables or some such.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: why would you want local and team build to run different versions of NuGet?

Comment: We do not want local and team builds to use different versions of NuGet.exe. We want both environments to always use the latest version.

For the developer, it's easy: simply set the DownloadNuGetExe property to true, as I showed in my original post.

The team build, however, is more difficult because the machine does not have Internet access and therefore cannot download the latest version of NuGet.exe. Instead, the TFS administrator puts the latest version of NuGet.exe in a well known location.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you need to check Nuget.exe into the .Nuget folder. Both your local workspace and your build server will then have access to and use the same version.

Visual Studio will notify you when you need to update NuGet.

Note: Having no internet access on a build server is not a security restriction. It is a draconian policy from the dark ages of IT and needs to be rethought. Ideally you don't want to check any binary assets into SCM and instead download them at build time.

That is best practice and your IT policy is forcing a dysfunction onto you.

Comment: As I said in my original post, we do NOT have NuGet.exe in the ".nuget" folder.

We don't want it there and we don't want to check it in because:
1. Every project will redundantly check in a common file (NuGet.exe) and ...
2. Eventually some projects would check in newer versions of NuGet.exe, potentially resulting in several versions of NuGet.exe in the repository.

Comment: Unfortunately this is the both the recommended and official solution to your problem.

Comment: I'm kinda surprised by the answers. To me, the official solution is not to check-in anaything related to NuGet (except maybe for the ".nuget\NuGet.config" file so VS doesn't try to check the "packages" folder in. That is, starting with both VS 2013 and TFS 2013. NuGet team wanted NuGet-related work out of MSBuild process, hecne NuGet.targets is deprecated. David Ebbo explains it all [here](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2014/01/the-right-way-to-restore-nuget-packages.html) with a link to the official NuGet website.

Comment: Correct - However you stated that you had no internet access on the build server which negates the out of the box solution. The ONLY other out-of-box solution is to use the pre-2013 way. Your workaround below will break every time the NuGet.targets file is updated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, at least my answer, turned out to be easy.

The ".nuget" folder contains "NuGet.targets" which downloads NuGet.exe, if needed. There is a DownloadNuGet task that contains a snippet of C# code to download NuGet.exe. As I described earlier, our TFS server does not have access to the Internet so this snippet always throws an exception.

My solution was to add some code to the exception handler to copy NuGet.exe from the server's well-known location to the ".nugget" folder, where it needs to be.

Using this modified DownloadNuGet, NuGet.exe will be downloaded on a developer's machine and will be extracted from the well-known location on the TFS server.

Here is the updated DownloadNuGet Task with a fair amount of logging:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="DownloadNuGet" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">
  <ParameterGroup>
    <OutputFilename ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
  </ParameterGroup>
  <Task>
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Using Namespace="System" />
    <Using Namespace="System.IO" />
    <Using Namespace="System.Diagnostics" />
    <Using Namespace="System.Net" />
    <Using Namespace="Microsoft.Build.Framework" />
    <Using Namespace="Microsoft.Build.Utilities" />
    <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
     <![CDATA[
        try {
           OutputFilename = Path.GetFullPath(OutputFilename);

           Log.LogMessage("***** Downloading latest version of NuGet.exe to: \"" + OutputFilename + '"');
           WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
           webClient.DownloadFile("https://nuget.org/nuget.exe", OutputFilename);
           Log.LogMessage("***** Latest version of NuGet.exe was successfully downloaded: " + OutputFilename);

           return true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
           // This exception handling code is what's new.
           Log.LogMessage("***** Exception while downloading latest versioln of NuGet.exe: " + ex.GetType() + " ==> " + ex.Message);
           Log.LogMessage("***** Attempting to find NuGet.exe in C:\\NuGet folder.");

           FileInfo nuGetExeFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\NuGet\NuGet.exe");
           nuGetExeFile.CopyTo(OutputFilename, true);

           String formattedFileLength = String.Format("{0:N0}", nuGetExeFile.Length);
           Log.LogMessage("***** NuGet.exe has been copied to \"" + OutputFilename + "\", File size: " + formattedFileLength);

           return true;
        }
     ]]>
    </Code>
  </Task>
</UsingTask
```

>

Comment: Remember that this will break every time the tooling is updated by visual studio. Do not rely on this method.